# Beginner @ SQL: SQL query Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to input this data as an example to learn sql but get this error 
 `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci' at line 5` 
Here is my SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `majors` (
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `about` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `majors` (`name`, `price`, `about`) VALUES('Applied Physics', 20.00, 'Applied Physics');
INSERT INTO `majors` (`name`, `price`, `about`) VALUES('Computer Science', 15.00, 'Computer Science');
```

Comment: You need to quote `20.00` and `15.00` and remove the comma after the last `DEFAULT NULL,`

Comment: @Fred-ii- -- no need to quote decimals, but the comma is the error.

Comment: @sgeddes Wouldn't the period throw an error? I thought it would've.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma after `DEFAULT NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `majors` (
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `about` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   <-- remove the comma
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2694